# Newman's modularity clustering for graphs

Tags: r, statistics, graph, cluster-analysis, modularity

I am interested in running Newman's [modularity](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1482622/) clustering algorithm on a large graph. If you can point me to a library (or R package, etc) that implements it I would be most grateful.

best
~lara

Comment: You may also try on stats.stackexchange.com .

Comment: For those interested in answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/newmans-modularity-clustering-for-graphs

Answer (score 9):

Use the igraph package for R:
http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/fastgreedy.community.html
this implements a fast algorithm for community finding using the newman-girvan modularity maximization method.

your code will look like this:

```
library(igraph)
# read graph from csv file
G<-read.graph("edgelist.txt", format="ncol")
fgreedy<-fastgreedy.community(G,merges=TRUE, modularity=TRUE)
memberships <-community.to.membership(G, fgreedy$merges, steps=which.max(fgreedy$modularity)-1)
print(paste('Number of detected communities=',length(memberships$csize)))
# Community sizes:
print(memberships$csize)
# modularity:
max(fgreedy$modularity)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure whether the open-source data visualization tool, [Gephi](https://gephi.org/), is running with this algorithm. As I know, it runs with the algo in paper: **Fast unfolding of communities in large networks**

It's also a modularity based methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a method in the excellent networkx package](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.newman_watts_strogatz_graph.html?highlight=newman#networkx.generators.random_graphs.newman_watts_strogatz_graph) that returns a Newman-Watts-Strogatz small world graph.

Comment: the question was to cluster a graph, not to generate it - which is what that function does